# How to solve Max under an integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, optimization

This is the first time I come accross a Max function inside an integral. I have looked around online and did not find anything about it. I would like to know the rules of what can I do when I have an integral over a Max. I am trying to figure out how one can get from equation (1) to equation (2). I get the intuition behind it, but want to know the mathematics behind it: the rules and steps.

The particular example that I came accross is the following:

$$w^{\ast }=\left( 1-\beta \right) b+\beta \int ^{w_{m}}_{0}\max \left\{ w,w^{\ast }\right\} dF\left( w\right)\tag{1}$$

If we substract $\beta w^{\ast}$ we get:

$$\left( 1-\beta \right) w^{\ast }=\left( 1-\beta \right) b+\beta \int ^{w_{n}}_{w^{\ast }}\left( w-w^{\ast }\right) dF\left( w\right)\tag{2}$$

1) How does the substraction enter the Max function under the integral? 2) How does it change the lower bound of integration? 3) Any links on the rules of max functions under integrals?

This comes from the search and matching models in economics (McCall model). We try to solve for w*, a particular wage, which is just a constant. The support of the distribution of wages goes from [0,$w_{m}$].

Comment: This is typically done by breaking interval into two subintervals on each of which the max function has different cases. Do you know where $w^*$ lies w.r.t. the interval $[0,w_m]$?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. w* lies anywhere on that interval. We solve for it by using equation 1. What you say makes sense, if break beta.w* into two integrals, one going from 0 to w* and another one from w* to wm (the upper bound of F(w), then I can get rid of the max term under the integral. My last question would then be: if I have a function on [-2,3], that looks like this: Max[2-x^2, 1-x^2+4x] and you want to substract 2x, what would you get as an answer?

Comment: It's generally true that $\max\{f(x),g(x)\}\pm h(x)$ is identically equal to $\max\{f(x)\pm h(x),g(x)\pm h(x)\}$. That follows from the fact that $f(x)\leq g(x)$ if and only if $f(x)\pm h(x)\leq g(x)\pm h(x)$. Is that what you mean? There are similar statements using multiplication and division, but you have to be careful about signs and zeroes. BTW, another way to say the same thing is $$\max\{f(x),g(x)\}=\max\{f(x)\pm h(x),g(x)\pm h(x)\}\mp h(x)$$

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. I did not know about these operations with max and min. After breaking the integral in 2 parts I can then substract out the Max term. I just came accross a book dealing with these same equations. Basically the slution gives a piecewise linear function that goes from a constant to a linear function at the point w*. Do you know where I can find more examples of operations with max and min?